# Is there anyway to extends JPA repository and extends another interface with abstract class defined?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want a EntityRepository extends from both CrudRepository interface and a self-defined CustomizedRepository interface, which has an abstract class defined. Is that possible?

I am currently thinking I can have a EntityRepository defined as

```
public interface EntityRepository extends EntityRepositoryCustom, CrudRepository<Entity, String> {
}
```

And for EntityRepositoryCustom, I have

```
public interface EntityRepositoryCustom {
    public Page<Entity> findEntitisOnCondition(Entity t, Pageable pageable);
}
```

with EntityRepositoryCustomImpl

```
public class EntityRepositoryCustomImpl<Entity> extends SelfDefinedRepositoryImpl<Entity> {
    @Override
    protected String getSOmething() {
        ...
    }
}
```

while SelfDefinedRepository and SelfDefinedRepositoryImpl are defined as below, respectively.

```
public interface SelfDefinedRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>  extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {
    Page<T> findEntitisOnCondition(T t, Pageable pageable);
}
```

and

```
public abstract class SelfDefinedRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements SelfDefinedRepository<T, Serializable>{

    public Page<T> findEventsOnCondition(T t, Pageable pageable) {
        ...
        getSomething();
        ...
    }

    protected abstract String getSomething();

}
```

This idea is failed. Can anyone help on how to implement a repository interface/implementation that I can have JPA repository functions and also can extends my self-defined abstract class? Thanks.

Comment: What is your purpose of doing it ? Do you just want to group your common methods in abstract class and reuse them ?

Comment: @Amit, I am trying to get a "generic search by criteria" function in abstract class.

Comment: Then you can use composition and not inheritance.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)?

Comment: What version of Spring Data are you using? Also how exactly does it fail? Since you have a non-abstract class to be used for the custom implementation, the abstract class in the hierarchy shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Add Custom Functionality to a Spring Data Repository](https://dzone.com/articles/add-custom-functionality-to-a-spring-data-reposito)

This can be helpful for your problem.

Comment: Link to an article is not an answer